# I install Anaconda3 on my pixelbook, but Spyder can't work...ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, spyder

> I have installed Anaconda3 on my pixelbook, but when I type spyder in the terminal and press enter:

`(base) zeropalau@penguin:~$ spyder`

> It just shows me the following error messages and spyder just can't work:

```
File "/home/zeropalau/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
File "/home/zeropalau/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/zeropalau/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 78, in <module>
    from qtpy.compat import from_qvariant
  File "/home/zeropalau/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/compat.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .QtWidgets import QFileDialog
  File "/home/zeropalau/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

> p.s. My Linux distro is Debian9

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What Linux distro are you using?

Comment: I check that It's Debian9

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing packages needed with "apt-file search".